# Counting Sort different approach

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In a counting sort algorithm, we initialize an count array with a size of Maximum Value in a given array. Runtime of this method is O(n + Max value). However with an extra loop, we can look for minimum and maximum value of given array;

```
for 0 -> Length(given_array)
   if given_array[i] > max 
      max = given_array[i]
   if given_array[i] < min
      min = given_array[i]
```

Then use that data to create the count array, lets say between 95-100. We could decrease the runtime in some cases tremendously. However, I haven't seen an approach like this. Would it be still a counting sort algorithm, or does it have another name that I don't know.

Comment: `"We would decrease the run time tremendously."` – that depends on the ratio of the range to the maximum value. Finding the minimum is typically omitted because it requires extra work which may not prove be worthwhile. But yes it would still be counting sort because the basic idea of counting occurrences is the same – just that the input array is effectively shifted.

Comment: Yes but one of the downsides of counting sort is the range of max value. We could compensate it in this way

Comment: That´s actually counting sort, just not usually implemented that way. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort): "Its running time is linear in the number of items and the difference between the maximum and minimum key values"

Comment: if I am not mistaken, its complexity would be still O(n+k), please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @aomerk if k is max - min, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting sort is typically used when we know *upfront* that values will be restricted to a certain range.

This range doesn't need to start at zero; it's absolutely fine to use an array of length six whose elements represent the counts of values 95 through 100 (or, for that matter, the counts of values from −2 to 3). So, yes, your approach is still "counting sort".

But if you don't know this restriction upfront, you're not likely to get faster results by doing a complete pass over the data to check.

For example: suppose you have 1,000,000 elements, and you *know* they're all somewhere in the range 0–200, but you think they're *probably* all in a much narrower range. Well, the cost of prescanning the entire input array is going to be greater than the cost of working with a 201-element working array, which means it costs more than it can possibly save compared to just doing a counting sort with the range 0–200.

> Runtime of this method is O(n + Max value).

The runtime is *O*(max(num_elements, range_size)), which — due to the magic of Landau (big-O) notation — is the same as *O*(num_elements + range_size). Your approach only affects the asymptotic complexity if max_value is asymptotically greater than both num_elements and range_size.